# What is the purpose of this pole [bollard] in my garage?

Tags: plumbing, construction

Why is there a three inch pipe filled with concrete sticking out of my garage floor? We've ruled out the obvious explanations: missle launcher, coffee table, NSA listening post, and Mario shortcut.

So what is it, and more importantly, can it be removed?

[image: picture of pole]

Edit: Thanks, Alaska Man, for providing the name of the thing: *bollard*.

Comment: How old is house? Did it once have an oil furnace?

Comment: It was built in 2000.

Comment: So not oil tank. Does it protect the hot water heater, or whatever that is behind it, from being whacked by an automobile?

Comment: That's what I've always assumed. I'm wondering whether it could be removed, if for example, a wall closed off that part of the garage.

Comment: NFPA 54 section 9.1.10

Comment: It is called a "Bollard", specifically an  impact resistant bollard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is to protect vehicles from damaging gas appliances that lie beyond. This is a code requirement in many jurisdictions, probably including yours, as most builders don't do anything they don't have to.

Comment: "most builders don't do anything they don't have to." Including apparently making appliance protection posts cosmetically attractive. :)

Comment: Yep, somebody should have primed it and painted it at least. White or grey would have been acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Mine are perfectly square and painted black. I have one which protects the water heater and one on the other side protecting the furnace. I am sure code requires them, as I do not believe a builder would add anything that is not required. Just slap some paint on it to make it a bit more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: So you have an opinion about them because you trust builders.  That's not really an answer - and I suggest your faith may be a little too high...